# Custom job name. Expression combination not working

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to set a custom job name in GitHub Actions using:

build:

```
runs-on: ubuntu-latest

strategy:
  matrix:
    project: ['A', 'B']

name: ${{ github.job }} ${{ matrix.project }}
```

When I run it I get 'A' or 'B' and not 'build A' and 'build B' as expected.

If I remove `${{ matrix.project }}` I then get 'build' in both cases.

What am I missing?

Comment: If this is in a workflow you can use the [run-name](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#run-name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `github.job` property is not available outside of execution steps. Description from the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context):

> The [`job_id`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_id) of the current job.
> Note: This context property is set by the Actions runner, and is only available within the execution `steps` of a job. Otherwise, the value of this property will be `null`.